# Web pages served by local IIS showing black diamonds with question marks

Tags: iis, browser, character-encoding, localhost

I'm having an issue in a .NET application where pages served by local IIS display random characters (mostly black diamonds with white question marks in them). This happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. IE displays the pages correctly for some reason.

The same pages in production and in lower pre-prod environments work in all my browsers. This is strictly a local issue.

Here's what I've tried:

- Deleted code and re-cloned (also tried switching branches)
- Disabled all browser extensions
- Ran in incognito mode
- Rebooted (you never know)
- Deleted temporary ASP.NET files
- Looked for corrupt fonts on machine but didn't find any

Other Information:

- Running IIS 10.0.17134.1
- .NET MVC application with Knockout

I realize there are several other posts regarding black diamonds with question marks, but none of them seem to address my issue.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are the pages served with an encoding? (content type header or `<meta charset=` element)

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. The explicit purpose of � is to indicate that character encodings are being misused. When users see that, they'll know that we've messed up and lost some of their text data, and we'll know that, at one or more points, our processing and/or configuration is wrong.

(Fonts are not at issue [unless there as no font available to render �]. When there is no font available for a character, it's usually rendered as a white-filled rectangle.)

Character encoding fundamentals are simple: use a sufficient character set (say Unicode), pick an appropriate encoding (say UTF-8), encode text with it to obtain bytes, tell every program and person that gets the bytes that they represent text and which encoding is used. The encoding might be understood from a standard, convention, or specification.

- Your editor does the actual encoding.
- If the file is part of a project or similar system, a project file might store the intended encoding for all or each text file in the project. If your editor is an IDE, it should understand how the project does that.
- Your compiler needs the know the encoding of each text file you give it. A project system would communicate what it knows.
- HTML provides an optional way to communicate the encoding. Example: [`<meta charset="utf-8">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta). An HTML-aware editor should not allow this indicator to be different than the encoding it uses when saving the file. An HTML-aware editor might discover this indicator when opening the file and use the specified encoding to read the file.
- HTTP uses another optional way: Content-Type response header. The web server emits this either statically or in conjunction with code that it runs, such as ASP.NET.
- Web browsers use the HTTP way if given.
- XHR (AJAX, etc) uses HTTP along with JavaScript processing. If needed the JavaScript processing should apply the HTTP and HTML rules, as appropriate. Note: If the content is JSON, the current RFC requires the encoding to be UTF-8.

No one or thing should have to guess.

## Diagnostics

- Which character encoding did you intend to use? This century, UTF-8 is so much the norm that if you choose to use a different one, you should have a good reason and document it (for others and your future self).
- Compare the bytes in the file with the text you expect it to represent. Does it use the entended encoding? Use an editor or tool that shows bytes in hex.
- As suggested by @snakecharmerb, what does the server send? Use a web browser's F12 network tab.

  - What does the HTTP response header say, if anything?
  - What does the HTML meta tag say, if anything?
  - What is the HTML doctype, if any?

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. Here are some of my findings: AJAX request: contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'; HTML Document: <meta charset="utf-8">; Response Headers (from browser console): Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8. So it seems I have the correct character set. One odd thing I noticed is when I opened the file in Notepad++ I could see that the encoding was UTF-8-BOM. I converted to UTF-8 but still no luck. Lastly, do you know why IE can display the characters correctly, but the other browsers do not?